# How can I queue calls to an async function and execute them in order?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-async

I have an async function that makes a network request, and I want to make sure that calls to the function wait for any previous calls to finish before making the network request. I also want to make sure that calls to the function result in network requests in the same order.

I came up with a basic solution using a `List<Completer>`. Below is a  simplified example that can be run on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/). Note that the example is very simplified and just makes a bunch of calls to illustrate the idea - in the real world the calls to the function could come from many different places - timers, user interaction, etc.

```
import 'dart:async';


int i = 0;

List<Completer> funcCompleters = [];
Future<void> func() async{ 
  // Make sure that subsequent calls wait for us 
  Completer c = Completer();
  funcCompleters.add(c);

  // Wait for any previous calls
  if( funcCompleters.length > 1 ) await funcCompleters[funcCompleters.length-2].future;      
  
  // Simulate a lengthy operation, such as a network request
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));

  // Generate some output so we can see what happens
  i += 1;
  print('i: $i   funcCompleters.length: ${funcCompleters.length}');

  // Let any queued calls execute 
  c.complete();
  funcCompleters.remove(c);
}


void main() async {  

  await func(); 
  func(); 
  func(); 
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 800), () => func());
  await func(); 
  func(); 
  await func(); 
  await func(); 
  func(); 
  func(); 
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 1), () => func());
  func(); 
}
```

It works, but it's clumsy.

Basically, the idea is to make the function queue up any call to it, and execute calls one after another.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: see `Future.forEach`

Comment: @pskink Thanks, although I should have made it clearer that the example code is very simplified, and that in my real app the calls to the function can originate from various places, such as timers and user interaction. I edited the question to make it more clear that the example is very simplified.

Comment: so use `StreamController` and  `Stream.asyncMap`- the docs say: *"Creates a new stream with each data event of this stream asynchronously mapped to a new event.

This acts like map, except that convert may return a Future, and in that case, this stream waits for that future to complete before continuing with its result."*

Comment: do you have the solution? I have the same problem with yours. I need to run a series of async function (dynamically generated) and take the result one by one in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Stream.asyncMap` to await futures in order

```
import 'dart:async';

final orderedFuturesController = StreamController<Future>();

Future preserveOrder(Future future) {
  orderedFuturesController.add(future);
  return future;
}

Future<void> anyAsyncFunction(int value) async => print(value);

Future<void> main() async {
  final subscription = orderedFuturesController.stream
      .asyncMap((future) async => await future)
      .listen((_) {}, cancelOnError: false);

  await preserveOrder(anyAsyncFunction(0));
  preserveOrder(anyAsyncFunction(1));
  await preserveOrder(anyAsyncFunction(2));
  preserveOrder(anyAsyncFunction(3));

  await orderedFuturesController.stream.isEmpty;
  await subscription.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to make all function await by this way no one will execute before the previous one and now all functions will execute in the same order you need if this is your aim from this question